Bicep Role Definition error - A Role Definition with the name <name> already exists, please choose a unique name for your new Role Definition
I'm trying to create a custom role definition, then assign my apps to that definition.
I create the role definition in a module, then assign separately.
However, when I deploy, I get the following error

A Role Definition with the name [Read Write Role] already exists,
please choose a unique name for your new Role Definition. ActivityId:
ba570f19-95e0-4b8b-9595-163f8e4ee857,
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0 (Code: BadRequest)

... on subsequent deployments.
param cosmosDbAccountName string

var dataActions = [
  'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata'
  'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/executeQuery'
  'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/items/*'
]

resource cosmosDbAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2023-11-15' existing = {
  name: cosmosDbAccountName
}

var roleDefinitionId = guid('sql-role-definition', cosmosDbAccount.id)

resource sqlRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlRoleDefinitions@2024-02-15-preview' = {
  parent: cosmosDbAccount
  name: roleDefinitionId
  properties: {
    roleName: 'Read Write Role'
    type: 'CustomRole'
    assignableScopes: [
      cosmosDbAccount.id
    ]
    permissions: [
      {
        dataActions: dataActions
      }
    ]
  }
}

output id string = sqlRoleDefinition.id


Then, when I want to assign this for each of my apps, I do something like

// this is passed in - based on the output from above module
param roleDefinitionId string

resource cosmosDbAccount 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2023-11-15' existing = {
  name: cosmosDbAccountName

  resource sqlRoleAssignment 'sqlRoleAssignments@2023-11-15' = {
    name: guid(roleDefinitionId, principalId, cosmosDbAccount.id)
    properties: {
      roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId
      principalId: principalId
      scope: cosmosDbAccount.id
    }
  }
}

I've based it on:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.documentdb/cosmosdb-sql-rbac/main.bicep
How can I achieve this?

I have also faced the similar problem and the solution worked out for me was, using the guid function directly inline to name property of sqlRole definition.
Instead of name: roleDefinitionId you can try using name: guid('sql-role-definition', cosmosDbAccount.id).
Though the using variable makes code more readable and should not make difference but for me it worked out.
My working code:
resource snUIRoleAssignmentApiApp 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
    name: guid(deployment().name, pApiAppServiceManagedIdentity)
    scope: snExistingUiAppService
    properties: {
        roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', pContributorRoleDefinitionResourceId)
        principalId: pApiAppServiceManagedIdentity
        principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    }
}


Thanks for your answer: I think similar to the answer I've posted which fixed it for me

The solution was surprisingly simple
Instead of
var roleDefinitionId = guid('sql-role-definition', cosmosDbAccount.id)
I used
var roleDefinitionId = guid('cosmosdb-role-definition', cosmosDbAccountName)
I think this is because of the way cosmosDbAccount.id was being determined, effectively created a new guid each time - meaning that it was trying to create a new role definition.
Using the static provided cosmosDbAccountName was more constant.
The answer from @Rohit Tatiya likely would work, too, but I haven't tried it.
